# bash command - using for i in `ls` with an if statement

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to clean up some directories that are all named in sequence 1001, 1002, 1003 and I can't seem to get this script to work to delete directories with a value less than a number

Contents of the DIR

```
1000 1001 1002 1003 1004 1005 1006 1007 1008 1009 1010 1011 1012 1013 1014
```

My command

```
for i in `ls`; do if (( $i < 1011 )) then echo rm $i -rf; done
```

but I get the error

```
-su: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: for starters, syntax of for needs 'do'. i.e `for i in *; do`

Comment: Additionally, there's no need to run `ls`; just use a glob: `for i in *; do ...; done`.

Comment: I've tried with an without do but I've edited the question so everyone doesn't just jump to that conclusion

Comment: @sputn1ck well, `if` needs `then`and `fi` too. Have you looked at even one other bash script ever? I'm not trying to be rude, but there's probably like a hundred bash scripts on your machine. Source: `/etc/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for i in *; do [ $i -lt 1011 ] && rm -fr $i; done
```

does the job.

Note: this really removes the files and does not just print the remove commands.

Comment: I would have preferred arithmetic context instead of [ x -lt n ], and I think you are missing a semicolon, but this solution is on the right track. `for i in *; do (( i < 1011 )) && rm -rf "$i"; done`

Comment: Thank you for the hint with the semicolon - was obviously a copy&paste error.

Answer (score 2):

Looping over ls is bad, as explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/418490/114895). Instead, use find, like so:

```
find . -regex '\./10[01][0-9]' -exec echo rm '{}' -rf \;
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
for i in `ls`; do if [ $i -lt 1011 ]; then echo rm $i -rf; fi; done
```

edited

Comment: true, it had other problems like missing 'fi', missing semicolon

Comment: that returns -su: [: -it: binary operator expected

Comment: that could be because you misspelled it, try with -lt not -it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
do
```

that's the reason.

```
for i in `ls` ; do whatever ; done
```